How to get multiple outputs from langchain.invoke when num_return_sequences>1
I want to get multiple sequences as output while using langchain.invoke() with the LLM parameter of num_return_sequences > 1. Does anyone know how to achieve this when using hugging face inference endpoints and langchain
I tried running langchain.invoke(), it returns only one output sequence
